# Opening an external file through a WebView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-webview, android-external-storage

So I have been at it for a while, and I really cannot get it to work. What I want is this:

- To access *some file* outside the project folder through a WebView.

Here is some code that I have been trying to get it working:

```
     String url = "file://///\\myProjectName" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ File.separator + "hw.html";

     WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebviewLOAD);

     webView.loadUrl(url);
```

I just get a *ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND* with any type of file. For a test-HTML file I created, I get this along with file not found error:

"The webpage at *file:///myProjectName/storage/emulated/0/hw.html* could not be loaded because"....

I tried removing `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()` but then i just get *file:///myProjectName/hw.html* along with the file not found error.

So I want to navigate to the right file and be able to open it, but I just can't seem to get it right. I'm open for any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically you can't do this. Instead you want to run a local server in the background and make the WebView and server work together.

I did it with Jooby with an SQLite database.